# How to use Swipe gesture recognizer for a long press up?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I'm using a swipe gesture recognizer to increase and decrease my counter with a swipe up and a swipe down.

I'm also offsetting my label by +10 when I swipe up and -10 when I swipe down.

everything is fine but once I swipe up, my label offset comes back to 0.
My goal is to leave the offset at +10 as long as I'm swiping up.
Here is my code:

```
private func setupSwipeGestures() {
   var swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  Selector("handleSwipes:"))
   var swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipes:"))

   swipeUp.direction = .Up
   swipeDown.direction = .Down

   view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)
   view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)
 }

func handleSwipes(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
   let increment: Int
   let offset: CGFloat

   // up or down
    if sender.direction == .Up {
      increment = 1
      offset = 10
    } else {
      increment = -1
      offset = -10
   }
```

Question:

- Is there a solution to keep the label at an offset of +10 as long as I'm swiping up, and at an offset of -10 as long as I'm swiping down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand from your question you want to store that +10 value when you swipe up and you can do it buy declaring your `increment` and `offset` globally into class like shown below:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //Declare it below your class declaration 
    var increment = 0
    var offset: CGFloat = 0

}
```

In your code you are declaring this two variables into your `handleSwipes` function so that when you call this function it will become 0 and your offset will always become +10 or -10 but once you declare it globally into class it will hold its value once it gets and If you want to increment it every time when `handleSwipes` function call then you can do it this way:

```
offset +=  10
offset -= 10
```

Same thing will happend to your `increment` variable you can change it as per your need and after that you can change label position this way into your `handleSwipes` function :

```
yourLbl.center = CGPoint(x: yourLbl.center.x, y: yourLbl.center.y + offset)
```

And your `handleSwipes` function will be:

```
func handleSwipes(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {


    // up or down
    if sender.direction == .Up {
        increment = 1
        offset +=  10
        println(offset)
        yourLbl.center = CGPoint(x: yourLbl.center.x, y: yourLbl.center.y + offset)
    } else {
        increment = -1
        offset -= 10
        println(offset)
        yourLbl.center = CGPoint(x: yourLbl.center.x, y: yourLbl.center.y + offset)
    }
}
```

Hope this will help.